# How to set (click) attribute from Angular component

Tags: angular

I am trying to set click attribute from Angular component as i am generating the dynamic  html from the component. When i try to Set Attribute onclick it is not working in Angular4.

```
var Atag = document.createElement("button");
Atag.setAttribute("onCClick","callFunction()");  // This is not working
```

I want result like this

```
<button (click)="callfunction() >Button</button>
```

How can i achieve this

Comment: it is not advisable to do direct dom modification when using angular. try to find angular way of doing dynamic html form

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a type:

```
setAttribute("onCClick")
```

should be

```
setAttribute("onClick")
```

Comment: That is a typo i used onClick only